# Change MenuFlyoutPresenter to align with button in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, flyout

I am trying to get the MenuFlyout to align bottom-left of the button. I can achieve this if i put the button at the left of the screen, but if the button is anywhere else the MenuFlyout is always centered right under the button. I suspect that I have to create a template and change a property in there but I do not know what I need to change to achieve this.

I've pasted my xaml below with a note of where i suspect I need to make the change. I am new to xaml, any help or guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
<Page
    x:Class="ButtonMenuFlyout.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ButtonMenuFlyout"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BasicTextStyle" TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="36" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle1" TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,0,20,16" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <!--[change property in here]-->
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button x:Name="buttonMenuFlyout" 
                    Content="..." 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                    HorizontalAlignment="right"
                    Padding="16,4"
                    Margin="120,10,0,5"
                    Background="White">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout  Opened="MenuFlyout_Opened" MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle1}">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" Text="Settings" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click"  />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" Text="Feedback" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click_1"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" Text="Notebook" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click_2" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: `You can set the placement of the `MenuFlyout` to `Bottom`, `Full`, `Left`, `Right` or `Top` of its parent, but there's no way to do `Bottom` **and** `Left` together explicitly in XAML.

If your flyout content is set, you should know its `ActualWidth` as well as `buttonMenuFlyout`'s. So you can apply a *left margin* of `Math.Abs((e.NewSize.Width - buttonMenuFlyout.Width) / 2)` to your `Grid` inside the style. In the case above, just add `Margin="78,0,0,0"` to it.`

Answer (score 1):

In your `MenuFlyout_Opened` method, you can explicitly call `ShowAt(UIElement, Point)` method.
This first parameter will probably be your `buttonMenuFlyout`; the second one, your offset which might roughly be `new Point(0, buttonMenuFlyout.ActualHeight)`.